# How can a Drupal view list items that are not related to other?

Tags: drupal, view

For several days, I have been trying to build a view, but couldn't. I need to list entities A that are not related with entities B.

Entities A are *users*. Entities B are *submissions*. A user can have many submissions or none. Submissions have *year* as a field.

I need to list users that don't have submissions for a certain year.

In a raw SQL statement it would be: 
select uid from users where uid is not in (select s.uid from submissions s where s.year = NNNN)

Is there a way to do this using Drupal 7 and Views 3? I'm sure that an expert can easily point me the right way to go.

Thanks in advance!!

Answer (score 0):

Another raw SQL way of doing it would be

```
SELECT uid
FROM users u
LEFT OUTER JOIN submissions s ON s.uid = u.uid AND s.year = NNNN
WHERE s.sid IS NULL
```

Note I'm assuming that your submissions table had a key field called sid.

So, join to the the submission table, and then filter out any rows where there is a join.

It should be easier to create this query using the views UI.